# Get exact data from json to react

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I have this JSON file :

```
[{
  "name": "bagette",
  "price": "0.200"
}, {
  "name": "farine",
  "price": "1"
}, {
  "name": "tomato",
  "price": "1.200"
}, {
  "name": "chocola",
  "price": "4.000"
}]
```

I want to get the data from json file to an array in react for example :

```
console.log(data[0][0]);    // bagette
console.log(data[0][1]);    // 0.200
console.log(data[1][0]);    // farine
console.log(data[3][1]);    // 4.000
```

I'm a beginner in React Please can someone help me to write the code ?

Comment: Can you explain why you would want that?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `data[0]['name']` and `data[0]['price']` ?

Comment: or data[0].name and data[0].price

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly clear what you are trying to do

Yu can use

```
console.log(data[0].name) //bagette
console.log(data[0]['name']) //bagette
```

or to iterate through every property in object:

```
for(var propertyName in data[0]){
    console.log(data[0][propertyName]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var data = [{
  "name": "bagette",
  "price": "0.200"
}, {
  "name": "farine",
  "price": "1"
}, {
  "name": "tomato",
  "price": "1.200"
}, {
  "name": "chocola",
  "price": "4.000"
}];

data = data.map(val=>Object.values(val));

console.log(data[0][0]);    
console.log(data[0][1]);    
console.log(data[1][0]);   
console.log(data[2][1]);
```

Comment: **Thank you that's what i need :)**

Comment: `Object.values()` does not guarantee the values to be in the correct order as object properties have no defined order in javascript. [To guarantee the order you will have to map the object to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order).

Answer (score 2):

You can parse `json` into an object with [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). Then you can map every object to an array. Note that this is the only way to totally ensure the [order of the properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order) is the desired one as object properties have no guaranteed order.

```js
const json = '[{"name": "bagette","price": "0.200"}, {"name": "farine","price": "1"},{"name":"tomato","price": "1.200"}, {"name": "chocola","price": "4.000"}]';

const data = JSON.parse(json);

const transformedData = data.map(obj => [obj.name, obj.price]);

console.log(transformedData[0][0]);    // bagette
console.log(transformedData[0][1]);    // 0.200
console.log(transformedData[1][0]);    // farine
console.log(transformedData[3][1]);    // 4.000
```

But I really don't know if that is a good idea. Why would you want to introduce [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants) when you already have named properties to access in your dataset.

Answer (score 2):

You can use  [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)  to return an array of array

```js
var data = [{
  "name": "bagette",
  "price": "0.200"
}, {
  "name": "farine",
  "price": "1"
}, {
  "name": "tomato",
  "price": "1.200"
}, {
  "name": "chocola",
  "price": "4.000"
}];

data = data.map((x)=>[x.name , x.price]);

console.log(data[0][0]);    
console.log(data[0][1]);    
console.log(data[1][0]);   
console.log(data[2][1]);
```

Comment: **Thank you that's what i need :) -**

Comment: @MrabetIheb The real question is still: Why do you need [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants) instead of named properties. Also mark answers as accepted / upvote if it helped you.

Comment: @trixn It's just an exemple so what ever named proprieties that i write or change the code still valid  and thank you by the way .

Comment: @MrabetIheb No it will not be valid. If you change the property names obviously your mapping from object to array will not work anymore. Arrays should be used as containers for elements of the same type. Using it like you do is an anti-pattern in most of the cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
let arr = [{
  "name": "bagette",
  "price": "0.200"
}, {
  "name": "farine",
  "price": "1"
}, {
  "name": "tomato",
  "price": "1.200"
}, {
  "name": "chocola",
  "price": "4.000"
}]

let data = arr.map(item=>{
    return [item.name, item.price]
})
```

That's you need?